# Bootstrap Slider animation duration

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a site and I would like to set my slider to make "softer" or slower transitions between the images. 
here is my site
http://www.hepi.hr/new/index.html

Someone assist and thank you in advance !

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

You can override the CSS `.carousel-inner > .item`
Go to bootstrap.css for reference. it's 0.6s by default.

eg.

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out left;
     -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out left;
       -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out left;
          transition: 1s ease-in-out left;
}
```

Hope this helps.